# regextract text between (" text ")

Tags: text, extract, quotes

I need to extract text between (" text ") from a column
I tried =REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(?<=(")\w+") but there's a formula parse error.

I tried =REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(?<=(")\w+") but there's a formula parse error.

I'm expecting a column with just text

Comment: Please tag the language you are using

Comment: Regex101.com is very handy for regex issues